# Is this group isomorphic to $S_n\times Z_m^n$?

Tags: group-theory

I have $n$ distinct objects. The objects are ordered in a row, and in each object has an orientation that is a multiple of $2\pi/m$. An action is an arbitrary permutation of the objects, as well as rotating some objects.

Is this group of actions isomorphic to $S_n\times Z_m^n$?

My concern is that when we reorder the objects, each object takes its own orientation to the new place, so permutation and rotation doesn't feel "independent" as it should in a direct product.

*(Sorry if this is an easy question, I'm just learning group-theory from wikipedia.)*

Comment: Instead of learning group theory from Wikipedia, learn it from a book.

Comment: The magic phrase you probably want to start with here is _semidirect product_.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I think you should also suggest a book :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the group you want is the wreath product $C_{m} \wr S_{n},$ where $C_{m}$ is the cyclic group of order $m.$ This group may be visualized in several ways. It is isomorphic to the group of all monomial matrices whose non-zero entries are complex $m$-th roots of unity. (A monomial matrix is one which has one non-zero entry in each row and one non-zero entry in each column). The order of this group is $m^{n}n!,$ which is the order of the group you proposed, but the wreath product is not a direct product: it is, as hinted in the comments, a semidirect product of an Abelian group of order $m^{n}$ with the symmetric group $S_{n}.$ Here, the Abelian group is a direct product of $n$ cyclic groups of order $m,$ and $S_{n}$ acts on the Abelian group by permuting the coordinates.

Comment: There are many good books on Group Theory, depending on how far you want to go: Aschbacher or Suzuki at a quite advanced level or more instructional texts can easily be found (everyone has their favorites: I don't want to impose mine).

Comment: I think it's a good idea to link this here: [Generalized symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_symmetric_group)

Comment: @Dave: Certainly relevant, though the reader probably needs to know what a wreath product is before reading that.